# MySQL Добавление данных.

Tags: php, mysql

При добавлении в таблицу users не получается добавить данные, если в них содержаться любые символы.Если только цифры то все работает отлично. Это проблема с кодировкой в базе?
Или в с чем это может быть связано? Сами переменные все значение выводят чтобы я туда не занес, а в базу не хотят заноситься.

Comment: Покажите предварительную подготовку данных и сам запрос. Думаю, что @Gorets вас в правильном направлении толкает.

Comment: Запрос выглядит так 

$add_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`login`,`email`,`password`) VALUES($login,$email,$password)");

Comment: Переменные в кавычки возьмите:

    $add_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login,email,password) VALUES('$login','$email','$password')");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экранируй скобками...

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте полю символьный тип

Comment: Тем полям, где должен быть текст я поставил тип Varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Я немного не понял вашего вопроса: данные в базу заносятся, то отображаются некорректно при последующем выводе или данные типа :

```
   !№;%:?*('")({}}{[])_
```

Просто не заносятся? Если второе, то используйте "функцию-спаситель" [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql_real_escape_string) она не только экранирует все спецсимволы, но и защищает от SQL-инъекций( слепых инъекций ), что, собственно, вытекает из первого.